# Clang: mark a specific warning as non error

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-warnings

I am trying to mark all warnings as errors to prevent new warnings from creeping in but I want to keep the existing codebase working so I mark some of them as non error with `-Wno-error=foo`. The thing is some warnings are still being reported as errors instead of warnings, even if they have been marked as no-error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -Xclang -include-pch -Xclang Pch/UI-ProjectScreen/c++.pch -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -Wextra -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wheader-hygiene -Wmissing-declarations -Wunreachable-code -Wuninitialized -Woverloaded-virtual -Werror -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-error=logical-op-parentheses -Wno-error=missing-field-initializers -Wno-error=non-virtual-dtor -Wno-error=pedantic -Wno-error=reorder -Wno-error=return-stack-address -Wno-error=sign-compare -Wno-error=switch -Wno-error=unreachable-code -Wno-error=unused-const-variable -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=unused-private-field -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=#warnings -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-extra-semi -Wno-backslash-newline-escape -Wno-missing-braces -isystem /Developer/Boost/1.57.0-Clang/include -isystem /Developer/Qt5.6.1-clang/5.6/clang_64/include -g -fPIC -std=gnu++1y -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -W -D_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_XMLPATTERNS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../../Modules/UI/ProjectScreen -I. -I/Developer/Boost/1.57.0-Clang/include -I../../../../ThirdParties/Glew/1.13.0/include -I../../../../ThirdParties/TBB/include -I/Developer/Qt5.6.1-clang/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Developer/Qt5.6.1-clang/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Developer/Qt5.6.1-clang/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtXml.framework/Headers -I/Developer/Qt5.6.1-clang/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtXmlPatterns.framework/Headers -I/Developer/Qt5.6.1-clang/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Headers -I/Developer/Qt5.6.1-clang/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -IMoc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -IUi -I/Developer/Qt5.6.1-clang/5.6/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Developer/Qt5.6.1-clang/5.6/clang_64/lib -o Obj/ProjectScreenWidget.o ../../../../Modules/UI/ProjectScreen/ProjectScreenWidget.cpp
../../../../Modules/UI/ProjectScreen/ProjectScreenWidget.cpp:597:9: error: missing field 'duration' initializer [-Werror,-Wmissing-field-initializers]
        }; 
        ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Obj/ProjectScreenWidget.o] Error 1
12:09:36: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
```

As you can see, I am passing `-Werror` as well as `-Wno-error=missing-field-initializers` so why is the compilation erroring on a `missing-field-initializers`? I could of course fix the warning but I'd like to understand what is happening first.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

**EDIT**: I just tried on http://gcc.godbolt.org/# and it seems to behave as expected, I cannot reproduce the same issue there...

Comment: A big one is actually fixing the problem, if within reach. You may also wrap it between pragmas that change behavior, however they probably are specific (I only know GCC-specific ones)

Comment: Yes, the idea is indeed to fix every single one and then disable the `-Wno-error=...` when that category is fixed, however I planned to chip at it over time and do not want to break the build until everything is fixed.

Comment: You should prefer to suppress *individual instances* of the warning, not the entire warning globally. That way, *new code* that you write will not compile unless you fix the problem, while old code that has not yet been refactored will be allowed to compile.

Comment: @CodyGray That would require to add a pragma for every warning generated (which is marked as an error), which defeats the purpose of doing a simple commit. If I'm going to change all these files, I might as well fix the warnings/errors...

Comment: Not necessarily. Making changes to actual code, no matter how simple and innocuous they seem, can have broad-reaching effects. Renaming a variable, for example, seems innocent, but can have unintended consequences and requires full regression testing. Adding a warning suppression would not have that same problem. But I see what you mean, you don't want to touch the code at all. In that case, you should consider compiling the modules separately, using these warning suppressions only when compiling modules containing old code, and *not* in modules containing new code.

Comment: Hmm, interesting approach. These modules are compiled separately, we are just using a common file to configure compiler warnings across all modules for simplicity's sake. I might just fix all these warnings that are wrongly marked as errors, maybe there aren't that many. I can't be sure as it stops the build...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue: I was using `qmake` to generate the makefiles and it was automatically adding `-W` after my settings, which was effectively ignoring all my warning options previously set.

So I changed the `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON` variable to remove that `-W` option and it fixed it.

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -Wall -W
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -Wall -W
```

I could have edited the makespec file as well but I think this solution is cleaner and more resistant to user errors (ie when (re)installing Qt and so on).